# PHP Variable being cut off in <option>

Tags: php, mysql, html, drop-down-menu

```
while ($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result))
{
$category = $row[0];
    echo "<option value=". $category .">". $category ."</option>\n";

}
```

Ok so basically, $category is a string like : Java Network Programming, and in the 'VALUE' part it only passes through "Java", where as in the second part, it passes through the whole string?

Any reason why, as this is kind of crucial. I have tried :

```
<option value=$category>
```

And still no luck, I just don't see why it works with one variable and not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a missing quotes issue to me:

```
while ($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result))
{
    $category = $row[0];
    echo '<option value="'. $category .'">'. $category ."</option>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to quote your HTML attributes.

```
echo "<option value='". $category ."'>". $category ."</option>\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Quote your attributes, and encode them for html via [`htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php),  in case they contain internal quotes.

```
echo "<option value='". htmlentities($category, ENT_QUOTES) ."'>". $category ."</option>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is happening bu if you try this it should work

```
echo "<option value='". $category ."'>". $category ."</option>\n";
```

Just enclose the $category in '' as I've done.

Hope this helps